# Using shortid package for mongoose with populate and equals function, Shorter human readable URLs and shorter IDs

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose

I want to use shortid package from npm with mongoose but I would love to know if it is possible to use equals() and how I can embed just the ids, for example, I have a user and I want to store in user schema all the liked posts (favShort in my schema) and then populate them. This is my schema that is using object id for populating. 
Shortid package link https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-shortid

````
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: shortid.generate,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  showNsfw: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  timezone: { type: String, default: 'CEST' },
  favShort: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Shortcut',
  }],
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  permissionLevel: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['member', 'moderator', 'premium', 'admin'],
    default: 'member',
  },
  country: String,
},
{
  timestamps: true,
}); ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer

---

I'm not sure if it will be any help to anyone but I'll post anyway

I have ended up using a [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid)  package for IDs and for slugs, I've used the plugin for mongoose [mongoose-slug-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-plugin)

---

**For referencing from other collection when using nanoid package make type a string**

```
favShort: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Shortcut',
  }],
```

---

## My Code

---

### Model

```
const mongooseSlugPlugin = require('mongoose-slug-plugin');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const nanoid = require('nanoid');

const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: () => nanoid(),
  },
  title: String,
  category: String,
  Description: String,
  className: String,
  description: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  nsfw: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  apps: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'App',
    },
  ],
  user: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    username: String,
    country: String,
  },
  meta: {
    downloads: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    fav: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    views: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  versions: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Version',
    },
  ],
  lastUpdate: Date,
});

postsSchema.plugin(mongooseSlugPlugin, { tmpl: '<%=title%>' });


module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postsSchema);
```

---

### Route

```
router.get('/posts/:slug', (req, res) => {
  Post.findOne({slug: req.params.slug}).exec((err, f) => {
    if (err || !f) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('back');
    } else if (f.versions.length === 0) {
      if (req.user === undefined) {
        res.redirect('back');
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      } else if (f.user.id.equals(req.user._id)) {
        res.render('posts/show', {
          csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
          f,
        });
      } else {
        res.redirect('back');
      }
    } else {
      const fS = f;
      if (req.cookies.cookieSeen === undefined) {
        fS.meta.views += 1;
        fS.save();
        res.cookie('cookieSeen', fS._id, optionsCookie);
        console.log(`set cookie and added views ${fS.meta}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`already seen this ${fS.title}`);
      }
      res.render('posts/show', {
        f,
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
      });
    }
  });
});
```