# Mongoose unique NanoID

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const user = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    nano_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: () => nanoid(7),
      index: { unique: true },
    },
...
}
```

How to run again `nanoid(7)` if is not unique? (run automatically and not get any error in console)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Prevent the error from happening in the first place by searching for a document with a similar Nano ID, if a document exists, regenerate a new Nano ID using a recursive function.

```
const { customAlphabet } = require('nanoid');
const alphabet = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const nanoid = customAlphabet(alphabet, 8);


// userRegistration controller or route...

  async function uniqueNanoId(query): Promise<string> {
    const nanoId = nanoid();
    const sameNanoId = await User.findOne({ nano_id:nanoId });
    if (sameNanoId) {
      return uniqueNanoId(query);
    }
    return nanoId;
  }

  const nanoId = await uniqueNanoId();
  const user = User.create({...userBody,nanoId});

//...
```

2. Catch the error - as @cachius hinted - and regenerate the unique Nano ID accordingly (not tested). Catching a duplicate key has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557473/how-to-recover-from-duplicate-key-in-mongoose-express)
3. Bonus: Ask yourself the question, do I really need both Default Mongoose IDs and Nano IDs? If not, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027302/using-shortid-package-for-mongoose-with-populate-and-equals-function-shorter-hu) is a simple solution.

```
// ...
_id: {
    type: String,
    default: () => nanoid(),
  },
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The database will throw an error you have to catch and react to by generating the same record again with a newly generated nanoid.